# NSArray may not respond (export to CSV code error)

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsarray, export-to-csv

I'm having trouble trying to export saved data from CoreData to a CSV file.  My ultimate goal is to save the information to CSV and attach it in an email.  Here's my code for exporting the data:

```
- (IBAction)exportData
{
mieleWasherAppDelegate *exportObjects = [[mieleWasherAppDelegate alloc] init];
[exportObjects managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest * allContacts = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[allContacts setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts"     inManagedObjectContext: [exportObjects managedObjectContext]]];
//  [allContacts setIncludesPropertyValues:YES]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * entries = [[exportObjects managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:allContacts error:&error];
[allContacts release];
//error handling goes here
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Contacts * entry in entries) 
{
    NSLog(@"Salutation: %@", entry.Salutation);
    NSLog(@"First Name: %@", entry.FirstName);
    NSLog(@"Last Name: %@", entry.LastName);
    NSLog(@"Company Name: %@", entry.CompanyName);
    NSLog(@"Email Address: %@", entry.EmailAddress);
    NSLog(@"Phone Number: %@", entry.PhoneNumber);
    [array addObject:entry];
}
NSError *saveError = nil;
[[exportObjects managedObjectContext] save:&saveError];
//more error handling here

// Export to CSV code
NSString *separator = @", ";
NSString *csv = @"";
for (NSArray *entry in entries) 
{
    csv = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@\n", csv, [entry Salutation],
           separator, [entry FirstName], 
           separator, [entry LastName], 
           separator, [entry CompanyName], 
           separator, [entry EmailAddress], 
           separator, [entry PhoneNumber]];
}
//If you want to store in a file the CVS
//[csv writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
//If you want to store in a file the CVS
//[cvs writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES];
}
```

Sorry if the formatting is a bit messy, but it's returning the following warning (repeated):

> NSArray may not respond to '-Salutation'

etc. until it goes through all fields.  I can't seem to figure out why it wont cooperate.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second `for` loop in the code you copy & pasted above, you're declaring `entry` as a `NSArray` object instead of a `Contacts` object.

Change `NSArray` to `Contacts` and the warning will go away.

Comment: Excellent, this worked. Many thanks.  As an addendum, is there a way in that code to check for null entries in the printout?  For example if I leave a blank entry, it's not supposed to save it but it seems to when I go to print out the results.  Is there anything I can do?